# Is the date when a theme was activated stored?

Tags: theme-development, switch-theme

Is there a date for when the currently active theme was activated stored anywhere?

If so, what's the best way to retrieve it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that information is stored by default, but you could hook in to the [`switch_theme` action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/switch_theme/) and store the date and time in an option.

Comment: It is not stored by default.